# One question about data locality in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

My environment is Hadoop 3.2.1 and Spark 2.4.5.

Three executors, each executor has two cores and 1g memory.

Configuration about data locality is `spark.locality.wait=3s`.

And I have a question about data locality in the below picture.

[image]

I know Spark prefers to compute the nearest data. But `slave1.lab.com` compute time more than 32 seconds compared to the other two executors. Why it could happen, I already configured `spark.locality.wait=3s`.

And I reviewed all the tasks in this stage, they are all `PROCESS_LOCAL`.

Why other executors prefer to be idle rather than share computing tasks?

Comment: Try repartition of your data and see

Comment: But the previous stage is normal.

Comment: Have you changed other locality wait settings by any chance? `spark.locality.wait.process`, `spark.locality.wait.node` ...

Comment: No, all configurations about locality are default.